# Estou com um problema ao criar quickstar com mongodb na aws

Tags: mongodb, amazon-aws

Quanto tento criar um aws quickstart com mondodb estou recebendo esse erro

> The following resource(s) failed to create: [VPCStack]. . Rollback requested by user.
>   Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:723891204374:stack/MongoDB-VPCStack-ZKCAQN2IIFMF/918b68b0-c7ff-11e7-88d9-50d5ca6e601e was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [PrivateSubnet3ARouteTableAssociation, NAT1EIP, NAT2EIP, PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation, NAT3EIP, PublicSubnet3RouteTableAssociation, PrivateSubnet2ARouteTableAssociation, PublicSubnetRou